# Socket server, I don't receive the message sent by my Server

Tags: java, sockets

I Have a client-Server connection..

Whem my server is connected to the client it must send a message through the outputstream and then print it when it receive the message from the inputStream. But when the client is connected I receive back the "Connected" message  but I don't see the "this is a Text message\n" sent my the Server

This is my **Server:**

```
public class Server1 extends JFrame{
    static JTextArea testoarea;
    static Socket socket;
    static ServerSocket server;

    public Server1(){
        testoarea = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane(testoarea));
        setSize(600, 700);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server1 server1 = new Server1();
        server1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        inizzializza();
        connetti();
    }


    private static void inizzializza(){
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(7100);
            showMessage("Server Iniziato\n");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }   
    }


    private static void connetti() {
        try {
            socket = server.accept();
            showMessage("Connected \n"); 

            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            output.println("this is a Test message\n");
            showMessage(input.readLine().toString()); 
            output.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private static void showMessage(final String text) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    testoarea.append(text);
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

this is what I get back:
[image]

Comment: Please try to not copy/paste the text from an editor next time, because a tab in stackoverflow code is actually equal to four spaces.

Comment: @Theolodis Oh Sorry, I didn't know it..

Comment: no problem, I fixed it for you.

Comment: oh, the problem is probably that you are flushing after receiving the message, but I guess that you get an answer only if you flush the request. TL;DR: `output.println("this is a Test message\n"); output.flush();` solves your problem.

Comment: Two remarks: you certainly doesn't want to add a "\n" in your `output.println()` call. Secondly, if you want call a `output.flush()` you want call it before the `input.readLine()`

Comment: @FabiF I did it before but nothing to do.. I don't receive the message

Comment: @Theolodis I tried to flush before reading the message but I don't receive nothing like before..

Comment: Then you have an error in the client. But you need to flush anyway before reding!

Comment: works for me if I do what Theolodis said. client writes a `this is a Test message` on the console. my client is just a telnet console though.

Answer (score 0):

Your `input.readLine()` is on your **server side** client input stream. That means it tries to read an **income** message **from** the client.

If you wan't read the message send by the server to the client from the **client side** (what I think you want, but I maybe misunderstood). You have to get the **client** socket input stream. 
The socket you get where you have probably call somewhere:

`Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 7100);`